10-15 guys compete for a job in a closed room
My friend told me about a movie, whose name he can't remember.
timeline : looked like a recent movie (from the 2000s)
genre : thriller
plot:
10-15 guys apply for a job and they are locked inside a room.
Inside the room, a guy comes and tells them a phrase/line/sentence, and
they have to decode it and find its meaning.
 During the test they can not leave
the room. If they leave the room, they are disqualified.
One by one people keep quitting and ultimately it boils down to 2 men.
He doesn't remember the ending very clearly, but eventually one guy wins.

Actually it's a lady that wins at the end.

Probably Exam:

The film is set in present-time United Kingdom in an alternate
  history. Eight candidates dress for what appears to be an employment
  assessment exam; they enter a room and sit down at individual desks.
  Each desk contains a question paper with the word "candidate",
  followed by a number, from one to eight. The Invigilator, a
  representative of the company named DATAPREV, explains that the exam
  is 80 minutes and consists of only one question, but there are three
  rules: they must not talk to the Invigilator or the armed guard at the
  door, spoil their paper, or leave the room. If they do, they will be
  disqualified.

If you read the whole plot you can see that there are two contestants left at the end.

I think the movie is Exam (2009)
This match with your discrption except that a white paper has been given to each person.  At the end they find out that the head chief of the company is one of the participants. 

Both answers are correct and urs is 1 min early, but Hegemon gave a longer answer. Single line answers are hard to accept because moderators can convert it into a comment. anyway +1 for you correct answer.

@Ankit Actually he/she answered 1 minute later :-)

@Hegomen I should mention i'm a he :-)

Oh yes ! Now I remember, you're right :-)
